# Expiring a cookie on page unload, then setting cookie on next page load

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, browser

I am setting a cookie `animals` via `setcookie('animals, json_encode(array('tiger')), time()+(3600*24), '/');` in PHP when a page is requested.

I am then expiring the cookie on page [`unload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload) with:

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function() {
    document.cookie = 'animals=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/';
});
```

This sets the cookie to be expired. This works great.

**The problem is** that when I refresh the page, `setcookie()` tries to set the cookie, but the browser has the cookie set to be expired, so the browser deletes the cookie when PHP comes back instead of using the new data/expiration time. So the cookie is deleted and I'm not able to access `animals` after the page has loaded.

This happens in both FF and Chrome. The problem is only on page refresh; if I go to a different site and then come back, or come to the page for the first time, the cookie is properly set.

Is there any way I can get the browser to understand not to delete the cookie, and instead use the new parameters? When does the browser decide to the delete the cookie, and why doesn't it look at the new params coming in from PHP?

Possible solutions (I would call them "hacks") are to add a unique identifier to each cookie (i.e. a timestamp) so animals-1407435704, so that each page load has it's own cookie. I could also echo out a `document.cookie` from PHP that sets the cookie, so after the page loads, the JS sets the cookie. But, I would rather see a solution that instructs the browser not to delete the cookie.

**Update:** I'm going with adding a unique identifier to each cookie, because I actually need to anyway to account for multiple tabs being open (and allow them to each exist on their own). I'm going to leave the question open because I don't understand why the browser does this.

Comment: So, your question is basically "I tell the browser to destroy the cookie when the page is closed, how do I tell the browser to keep the cookie if I open the page again?"  How about -- just don't kill the cookie on page unload?

Comment: @zebediah49 The cookie is part of the options of a component on the page. If a user leaves the page without saving anything, I don't want those options to be still loaded when they come back to create something else.

Comment: So then it's working as intended.  Reloading the page is a shortcut for "close the page, then open it again".  Perhaps a short-term cookie life would make more sense -- have it expire after, say, half an hour (long enough that an accidental close/reopen will preserve their work, but short enough that coming back the next day will reset it).

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution should reset the cookie:

```
document.cookie = 'animals=; Max-Age=0'
```

Comment: Would this set the cookie to expire right away, or would it expire at the end of the browser session? Also, how would I set Max-Age via PHP?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to check and see if the cookie exists and then react accordingly.

If the cookie still exists on a fresh load, keep checking on a delay until deleted, then add it again:

```
waitToSetCookie(){
    if (checkCookie(animals))
            setTimeout(waitToSetCookie(), 1000);
        else
            setcookie('animals, json_encode(array('tiger')), time()+(3600*24), '/');
}
```

Comment: This is assuming that the problem is not deleting the past cookie quick enough (which would seem to make sense given the time delay of navigating elsewhere resolving the issue)

Comment: Just tried it, and `if(isset($_COOKIE['animals'])) {` always come back as false - I'm assuming PHP is reading that it is expired.

Comment: Have you tried checking, setting, and deleting the cookie via JS instead of PHP? (not sure if this is an option)

Comment: The PHP code that sets the cookie a component that other parts of the site use, so I'm not really easily able to carry the value of what the cookie would be set to up to the javascript.